# undefined symbols in .o file

Tags: c, assembly, embedded, microcontroller, 68hc12

I am using icc12 to make a project that contains three files:

.s file containing a series of subroutines in assembly language

.h file with a list of the functions

.c program containing my main code where I call upon my subroutines

My issue is that when I compile my C program the compiler displays the following errors:

```
 !ERROR file 'filename.o': undefined symbol '_lcd_putstr'
 !ERROR file 'filename.o': undefined symbol '_lcd_init'
 !ERROR file 'filename.o': undefined symbol '_lcd_move'
 !ERROR file 'filename.o': undefined symbol '_lcd_clear'
```

I have been doing some research into what a .o file actually is and I understand that it is an object file containing machine code that the CPU understands.  They contain information that allow a linker to see what symbols it requires in order to work.  I still don't understand how I can fix these errors though from this.  I have checked for any grammatical mistakes but I cant seem to locate any.  Is anybody able to offer some help on how I can make these symbols 'defined' in my .o file?

My build commands are

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <mc9s12dp512.h>
 #include "lcd.h"

 int main (void)
 {
      unsigned char keycode;
      int keysave = 0;

      DDRB = 0x00;    /* make Port B an input port */

      lcd_init();  // initialise the lcd module
      lcd_clear(); // clear the lcd module

      // print the welcome message on the LCD module
      lcd_putstr(" message A ");

      // move the cursor position down a line
      lcd_move(1,1);
      lcd_putstr(" message B ");

      // move the cursor position down a line
      lcd_move(1,2);
      lcd_putstr(" message C ");

      // move the cursor position down a line
      lcd_move(1,3);
      lcd_putstr(" message D ");
```

Excerpt from assembly file for `_lcd_putstr`

```
 _lcd_putstr::
             pshx
             tfr     d,x             ; Transfer address of string to X
             ldaa    #WRDATA         ; Set up command for write data
             jsr     WriteBytes      ; Call subroutine to write byte to LCD
             pulx
             rts
```

Comment: Please post your build commands, and also indicate where the `_lcd_xxx` functions are defined (i.e. in which source file).

Comment: @PaulR my source file contains all the `_lcd_xxx` functions in assembly language and the function definitions.  They are all declared in the source file with an underscore and followed by two colons for example `_lcd_putstr::`  

My build commands are as follows -

Comment: Please hit the [edit] link above to add further information to your question (such as the build commands, relevant source code, etc), rather than using comments.

Comment: quick question: is icc for ImageCraft Compiler or Intel C Compiler?

Comment: @purplepsycho it is for ImageCraft

Comment: @PaulR I have edited the question, thanks.

Comment: OK - I've removed the misleading `icc` tag now (the `icc` tag is for Intel's ICC compiler - when adding a tag please hover over it and read the tool tip to see if it's appropriate).

Comment: Please include the *build commands* in your question, i.e. how you are invoking the compiler and linker to compile/assemble the two files and link then into an executable. Most likely you are getting link errors due to the way you are trying to build.

Comment: Can you show us your build commands please?

Comment: @PaulR i use the ImageCraft _make project_ button which connects the three files together and I compile the .c file to the output and I get these errors.  I have no typed out written commands.

Comment: @user_1 I see. Can you show us an excerpt of the assembly file please? It might be that you forgot to mark the `_lcd_putstr` etc. symbols as global.

Comment: @fuz I added it to the question using my code for `_lcd_putstr`

Comment: Are there any commands that can dump the symbol tables in the .o files?

Comment: in the assembly source file or the c file? @Ian

Comment: @user_1 In the .o files.

Comment: oh right. I am not actually sure as I can't open the .o file, what would these commands look like? @Ian

Comment: @user_1 Well, when developing in a Unix/POSIX style environment for the native host (not cross-compiled), the command would be `nm`, and for Microsoft's native compilers, the command would be `dumpbin`. But I do not know what the equivalent command for the ImageCraft development environment would be called, or even if it has one at all.

Comment: In that case then there is not any dump commands in the object file @Ian

Comment: @user_1 Try to use a `global` directive or whatever it is called to make the symbol `_lcd_putstr` global. By default, symbols in object files are local and not visible to the linker.

Comment: You are going to have to consult your compiler manual regarding how to mix C and assembler. In this case the ABI is defined by the compiler, since this is a bare metal MCU (Unix and PC programmers need not worry their pretty heads). Different compilers will use different calling conventions of how to pass parameters through accumulators and the stack. I only know how Codewarrior does this, so I can't help with Imagecraft. Once you know how the calling convention works, you should be able to write C prototypes for assembler functions, or XREF C functions from assembler.

Comment: @user_1 Why two colons in assembly code ? Only one is not sufficient ?

Comment: Despite the text, you have not posted the "build commands"; that is a fragment of your C code.  You would do well to post the exact command line used to invoke the build and *all* build log output - not just the errors.

Comment: The most likely problem is that you are not building and linking the assembly file.  That is why you are being asked for the build commands/log, because that would reveal whether the was true or not immediately.  You cannot be helped if you don't provide the information requested.

Answer (score 1):

Often, the compile puts an underscore before the identifier when it compiles the c source. If your compiler does that, you must add the underscore to the subroutine names in the assembler files, and omit it in the .h file, e.g.:

Name in assembler file: `_lcd_putstr`

Prototype in .h file: `int lcd_putstr(void);`

Use in .c file: `n= lcd_putstr();`

---

EDIT:

> "when I compile my C program the compiler displays the following errors [...]"

The errors you show us are not compiler errors. They are linker errors. The C file is compiled into a .o file. All the requried .o and lib files are combined by the linker into an executable. It is in this stage that the error messages are generated: the linker can't find these symbols.

You must instruct your compiler to generate a .o file. Then you must issue a command to link the objects into the executable. It seems you don't have or don't issue this command. Please consult the documentation of your development tools how to issue a link command with all required objects.

Comment: sorry I never mentioned but I have them typed in exactly how you have them there, my subroutines in the .s file have an underscore before them and they have two colons after. for example....      ' _lcd_putstr::'